# How magnify scale of items on touch in swift

Tags: animation, swiftui

I am new to iOS development. I'm trying to create an effect like the following figure shows. There is a list of items in a view, When user touch the view, a portion of the view is scaled from the touch center (but the top is aligned). When touch moves, the magnification effect moves as well with a smooth animation.
[image]

Look forward to any kind of help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Next should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/59798786/12299030.