# SwiftUI animation unwanted fade and z-order mixup

Tags: swift, swiftui

For learning purposes i'm trying to create a Pokedex with SwiftUI. I created a Login mask covered by 2 images. I wanted to create an effect where the Pokedex opens up by sliding the upper image up and the lower image down, once done revealing the login mask.

Doing so causes 2 weird behaviors i don't know how to overcome.

1. The login mask behind the image seems to fade in/out when the images slide in/out
2. Upon sliding out the images instantly move behind the Login Mask (gray-black box)

Any idea what causes this? I'm using following code to animate this

```swift
// as View modifier
.transition(.move(edge: .top))

// to open/close the pokedex
withAnimation(.linear(duration: 1)) {
    openPokedex.toggle()
}
```

The code is open source so it might be easier to just check it out directly rather than copying tons of lines here.
[LoginView](https://github.com/Deitsch/Pokedex/blob/main/Pokedex/Views/LoginView.swift)
[github.com/Deitsch/Pokedex](https://github.com/Deitsch/Pokedex)

[image]
[image]

Comment: You need `zIndex` modifier, like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59798786/12299030.

Comment: It worked but why is the order of the view not enought by itself? It initally covers and then the z-order breaks on transition? Also any idea why the black-gray square fades?