# SwiftUI: how to implement drawable grid?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to port my Pathfinding Visualizer web app from JS to SwiftUI on MacOS. [Web App hosted on GitHub](https://neilotha.github.io/pathfinding-visualization-web/)
Currently stuck on implementing the grid's input.

I want to be able to draw walls on the grid by dragging the cursor.

[Full Code On GitHub](https://github.com/Neilotha/Pathfinding_Visualization_SwiftUI_MacOS/tree/main/Pathfinding_Visualization)

Here is my current method:

```
struct NodeView: View {
  @State var nodeInfo: Node
  @Binding var mouseDown: Bool

 
  var body: some View {
      Rectangle()
        .fill(nodeColor(state: nodeInfo.getState()))
        .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
        .onHover { hover in
            if mouseDown && hover {
                print("mouse hover")
                nodeInfo.toggleWall()
            }
            if hover {
                print("node: \(nodeInfo.id) hovered!")
            }
        }
        .pressAction {
            if mouseDown == false {
                mouseDown = true
                print("mouse down")
                nodeInfo.toggleWall()
            }
        } onRelease: {
            mouseDown = false
            print("mouse up")
     }
 }
```

The code for `pressAction`

```
struct PressActions: ViewModifier {
var onPress: () -> Void
var onRelease: () -> Void

func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
        .simultaneousGesture(
            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                .onChanged({ _ in
                    onPress()
                })
                .onEnded({ _ in
                    onRelease()
                })
        )
    }
}

extension View {
    func pressAction(onPress: @escaping (() -> Void), onRelease: @escaping (() ->   Void)) -> some View {
        modifier(PressActions(onPress: {
            onPress()
        }, onRelease: {
            onRelease()
        }))
    }
}
```

The mindset is when a node detects that the mouse is pressed it will update the `mouseDown` variable passed down from the grid.

The other nodes on the grid will respond to the cursor hovering over them when `mouseDown` is true.

However this approach doesn't work as I wished. The nodes won't respond to the cursor when dragged across them most of the time. And even if it does, the response is quite laggy.

Is it because I'm using dragGesture to listen to mouse down and mouse up during the whole dragging action?

Currently trying to use NSEvent instead of gestures.

---

Update:
I've changed the implementation to using stateGesture on the content view instead of each node view.

But the time it takes from input to render seems proportional to the grid's size.

Also it seems the view won't update while the cursor is moving.

Comment: Why simultaneousGesture, is it in ScrollView?

Comment: It's not a ScrollView. The grid is inside a navigation view. I copied that piece of code from https://serialcoder.dev/text-tutorials/swiftui/handle-press-and-release-events-in-swiftui/. I'm fairly new to SwiftUI so does simultaniousGesture only work when the parent has its own trigger is well ?

Comment: If you inject nodeInfo from outside and change it then it should be Binding as well, not State. Actually needed minimal reproducible example, it might be in different code - I don't see issues here with gesture handling, but reporting mouseDown outside might cause waterfall effect or some other issues.

Comment: I added the GitHub link for the source code. I'm not sure if it's because I'm trying to trigger gesture across multiple views at the same time. Or the state isn't updated immediately.

Comment: Yes, I reviewed - it is not very appropriate approach, onHover is not accurate and slow, moreover such code generates many updates from different views. It would be more appropriate to have only one source of drag events - entire board, and which node to highlight is calculated in place and change in model. Here is something similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59798786/12299030.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried the implementation suggested by the post [SwiftUI drag gesture across multiple subviews](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59798786/12299030)

This approach works. However, the input lag is proportional to the grid's size.

After profiling and searching for the cause of such behavior.

My theory is there's simply too much subviews inside contentView, causing SwiftUI to spend a considerable amount of time on diffing when the state changes.(If I'm wrong you're welcome to correct me)

I'm not sure if there is a way to solve this inside SwiftUI.

Eventually I choose to implement the grid view using UIKit's UIView.

With this approach I successfully implemented a grid that can draw walls with little to none latency.

If your interested with the code, the code is posted at [GitHub](https://github.com/Neilotha/Pathfinding-Visualizer-IOS/tree/main/Pathfinding%20Visualizer)